# in microbit how to make variable save?

Tags: variables, bbc-microbit

[image] [image]
i want make reading  variable led in a button and b.
and button c(a+b) show variable led.
if i push the button a b b a than show the led a b b a

but can only show when i push the last button

so help me
how to make?

(Button.AB, function () {
   showImage(0)
})
(Button.A, function () {
   images.createImage(
        `. . . . .
        . # # # .
        . # # # .
        . # # # .
        . . . . .`
)
})
input.onButtonPressed(Button.B, function () {
    mos = images.createImage(
        `. . . . .
        . . . . .
        # # # # #
        . . . . .
        . . . . .`
)
})
let mos: Image = null
 images.createImage(
    `. . . . .
    . . . . .
    . . . . .
    . . . . .
    . . . . .`
)

there just read only push last button

Comment: really i'm so sorry, the code page  didn't work.
so

Comment: input.onButtonPressed(Button.AB, function () {
    mos.showImage(0)
})
input.onButtonPressed(Button.A, function () {
    mos = images.createImage(`
        . . . . .
        . # # # .
        . # # # .
        . # # # .
        . . . . .
        `)
})
input.onButtonPressed(Button.B, function () {
    mos = images.createImage(`
        . . . . .
        . . . . .
        # # # # #
        . . . . .
        . . . . .
        `)
})
let mos: Image = null
mos = images.createImage(`
    . . . . .
    . . . . .
    . . . . .
    . . . . .
    . . . . .
    `)

Comment: just fixed the images that were not showing properly.